# page is not rendered in ie8. Renders only in compatibility view mode

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I have problem with rendering the page in IE8+ browsers and it works fine with FireFox. If i keep the code as below then it does not render the page in IE8+. It renders only in compatibility view mode but not in normal mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!--[if lt IE 7]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html lang="en" class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <!--<![endif]-->

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/styles.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./public/js/myjs.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>

    </html>
```

But if i change the code as below. Then it renders properly without switching to compatibility view mode in IE8+.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html lang="en" class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <!--<![endif]-->

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/styles.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./public/js/myjs.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>

    </html>
```

what is the difference in both the codes?

Thanks!

Comment: Your DOCTYPE should be the first thing in your document. Can you change it to simply: <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: yeah..i tried..if i move it to first line then the page is not rendered. it renders only in compatibility view mode...

Answer (score 6):

`<!DOCTYPE HTML` should be on the first line of the document in order to swtich to standard (i.e. non-compatibiliy) mode.

If you really need compatibiliy mode, you may just add blank line at the beginning of the file, or some comment like `<!-- Yes, I like quirksmode -->` to make your action explicit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is page is rendered only when i switch to compatibility view mode. But without switching to it, it has to render. what should i do? if i keep doctype in first line then page is not rendered. it renders only in compatibility view mode.